# How insert class to json file

Tags: java, json

I have a class named usersJ where there is a single field of type list .
I want to insert the information in the class into  json file.
I do not know what is missing in the code, but I can not write to the file for some reason and it remains empty.
I tried to do this with the following function (I also included the UsersJ and User code) -

```
public class UsersJ {
    private List<User> users;

    public UsersJ ( ConcurrentHashMap<String , User> allUser){
        users = new ArrayList<>(allUser.values());
    }
}
```

user class -

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String country;
    private LinkedList<MoviePairInfo> movies;
    private int balance;
    private final String type;


public User( String _username,String _password , String _country){
    username = _username;
    password = _password;
    country = _country;
    balance = 0;
    type = "";
    movies = new LinkedList<>();
}
}
```

and the function -

```
 public void write_to_user( ConcurrentHashMap<String , User> allUser){
       UsersJ users = new UsersJ(allUser);
       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
       String path = "Users.json";
       try{
           FileWriter a = new FileWriter(path);
           gson.toJson(users , UsersJ.class , a);
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Try closing the `FileWriter` after the `gson.Json(...)` call with `a.close()`

Comment: That was the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: Just as a couple notes to add to this, here is an example of using FileWriter: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-filewriter-class, and here is a method description of Gson.toJson(): https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson-java.lang.Object-java.lang.reflect.Type-com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter-